# empty return of incoming keywords

Tags: php, performance, seo

by using `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` for detecting incoming google keywords , it returns a string that shows `q=` is empty.

it returns a url like this:

```
http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=29&ved=0CGUQFjAIOBQ&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.myurl.com%2Fq%h2F%2Bsvxhk&ei=i6HLT43kC4bHswb9tZnCBg&usg=AFQjCNFecbCFrl6ijGLa57krctOcXiDZ0A&sig2=xprGQXlaVyxxYK646t1Oaw
```

as you see there is not any detectable keyword. what is wrong and solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing wrong it's intended behaviour [Google article](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/10/accessing-search-query-data-for-your.html).

Google recommends using: [Search queries](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35252)